# convert plot to RGB array

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I want to convert a plot generated with matplotlib to an rgb array. In my case, I want to draw two circles using matplotlib. Currently, there are two problems:

1. You can still see the space taken by the axes
2. The circles aren't circles anymore in the resulting rgb array

Here is the code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
```

Generate the plot:

```
def drawImage(color, posx, posy, radius):

    posx_left, posx_right = posx
    posy_left, posy_right = posy

    radius_left, radius_right = radius

    fig = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.gca()

    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_axis_off()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    circle_left = plt.Circle((posx_left, posy_left), radius=radius_left,color=color)
    ax.add_patch(circle_left)

    circle_right = plt.Circle((posx_right, posy_right), radius=radius_right,color=color)
    ax.add_patch(circle_right)

    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    width, height = fig.get_size_inches() * fig.get_dpi()
    img = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8').reshape(int(height), int(width), 3)
    return img
```

Generate plot and save as array:

```
color = "blue"
radius = 0.2, 0.12
posx = 0.0,0.8
posy = 0.3,0.7
img = drawImage(color,posx,posy,radius)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: Final plot]

Comment: If the one plot is shown *within* the other axes, how should the axes overlap? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I just want to convert a plot generated with matplotlib as an rgb array. Currently however, as you see in the picture, the plot generated with matplotlib is somehow embedded in the larger rgb array.